# 'npm install connect' error

Tags: json, node.js, npm, npm-install

I;m watching [this](https://youtu.be/54aol-U_1es) video tutorial on Node.js and I get this error as soon as I run `npm install connect`:

```
user:15-connect$ npm install connect
/home/path/to/NodeJS/Bucky_tutorials/15-connect
└─┬ connect@3.4.1 
  ├─┬ debug@2.2.0 
  │ └── ms@0.7.1 
  ├─┬ finalhandler@0.4.1 
  │ ├── escape-html@1.0.3 
  │ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0 
  │ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1 
  │ └── unpipe@1.0.0 
  ├── parseurl@1.3.1 
  └── utils-merge@1.0.0 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/path/to/NodeJS/Bucky_tutorials/15-connect/package.json'
npm WARN 15-connect No description
npm WARN 15-connect No repository field.
npm WARN 15-connect No README data
npm WARN 15-connect No license field.
```

Comment: My 50ct.: either you're in the wrong directory (the one with packages.json) or you haven't setup npm for your project => `npm init` first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think thats a warning, not an error.  If you don't have a package.json file yet, you can easily create one with the `npm init` command.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have package.json , it's just a warning. I dont see any error. just make sure if there is a folder called `node_modules/connect` after `npm install connect`